# Delete part of expression from the long string and also the opening & closing bracket should be same in number

Tags: python, regex

Given below is the expression which needs to be deleted based on the user input

```
one =(DESCRIPTION =(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = abc)(SERVICE_NAME = xyz)))
two =(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(PORT = 212))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = abc)))
```

If user gives the input as 'one' then the output should be given below. It should delete complete expression for one and print the expression for two

```
two =(DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)(PORT = 212))(CONNECT_DATA = (SERVER = abc)))
```

Comment: What type of expression is this ? Is it a string ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
two\s*=\s*\(.*?\)(?=\s|$)
```

You can use this.Just replace `two` with `one` or whatever user gives and replace with ``.

You can create this pattern at runtime based on user input.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/lS5tT3/4

Comment: In the case of new line it won't work. eg two =( /n DESCRIPTION =(ADDRESS = (PROTOCOL = TCP)